# Subscribed Members can Unlock Un-released Books

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, models, has-many-through, subscription

I've created an App where a signed up Members can access our Library of Books. If the Book's release_date is greater than today's date. Members have the ability to purchase an Unreleased Book & Unlock It(Early Bird Special).

But if the Unreleased Book has not been purchased, I would like to display it as Coming Soon.

I am having trouble creating a method/view that will help me display our Regular Books, Unreleased Books, & Purchased Books to a current_user.

My Code is Below, any help will be greatly appreciated.

**VIEWS**

```
<% if current_user.member? %>
  <% @books.each do |book| %>

    <% if book.unreleased_book %>

      ###I am having trouble getting this conditional or loop to work
      <% if current_user has purchased the book %>
         LIST ALL PURCHASED BOOKS
      <% end %>
      <% if current_user has not purchased the book %>
         LIST ALL UNRELEASED BOOKS
      <% end %>

    <% elsif book.release_date <= Date.today %>
         LIST ALL AVAILABLE BOOKS
    <% end %>

<% else %>
  DISPLAY ALL BOOKS AS STATIC
<% end %>
```

**MODELS**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :member

    has_many :books, through: :orders
    has_many :orders, :dependent => :destroy

end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :book_id, :order_date, :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :book

end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :pages, :title, :available_in, :price, :release_date

  has_many :orders
  has_many :users, through: :orders

  ###Definition of unreleased books
  def unreleased_book
    Date.today < self.release_date
  end

end
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

def index
  @books = Book.all
    @orders = current_user.orders
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json  { render :json => @issues }
    end
  end
end
```

SCHEMA

```
create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "email"
  t.boolean  "member",             :default => false ###Becomes Member on SignUp
  t.datetime "created_at",         :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",         :null => false
end

create_table "orders", :force => true do |t|    ###Created when Purchased a BOOK
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "book_id"
  t.date     "order_date"
  t.datetime "created_at",            :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",            :null => false
end

create_table "books", :force => true do |t|
  t.string   "title"
  t.string   "pages"  
  t.text     "description"
  t.decimal  "price",              :precision => 8, :scale => 2
  t.date     "release_date"   ###If Release_Date > Time.Now then Book is Unreleased
  t.datetime "created_at",         :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",
end
```

Comment: which version of rails are you using?

Comment: got it. no wonder you are using `attr_accessible`

Answer (score 1):

I think your model relations are a bit off. Here is my suggestion:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :member

  has_many :orders # a user typically can have many orders
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :book_id, :order_date, :user_id

   belongs_to :user #each order belongs to a single user
   has_many :books # one order can have consist of many books

end


 class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :description, :pages, :title, :available_in, :price, :release_date

   belongs_to :order 
   has_many :users, through: order # since a book belongs to an order and an order belongs to a user, a book has many users goes the logic

 end
```

Move the logic in your view to a help. consider using the `case expression`. This helper will give you an outline.

```
module BooksHelper 
  ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper #this will give access to Url helpers 

  def purchases(book)
    case book
    when book.unreleased_book
      link_to path_to_new_action #configure this path depending on how you set up your routes. 
    when  current_user has purchased the book
      #LIST ALL PURCHASED BOOKS
    when current_user has_not purchased the book
      #LIST ALL UNRELEASED BOOKS
    when book.release_date <= Date.today
      #LIST ALL AVAILABLE BOOKS
    else
      #DISPLAY ALL BOOKS AS STATIC
    end
end
```

then in your `VIEWS`, render the helper like this.

```
<% if current_user.member? %>
 <% @books.each do |book| %>
    <%= purchases(book) %>
 <% end %>
```

This will keep your views clean.

`books controller`:

since you changed your models associations, you need to tweak your controllers. 
First, load the order (a specific order) by id. Then, since `order has_many :books`, find all the books associated with that order.

```
def index    
  @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
  @books = @orders.books
end
```

or if you have defined the `current_user.orders`, then you can do `@orders = current_user.orders`. but the way you have it now, the first line is not doing anything

Comment: thanks for helping me set up the models, but the actual case expression is what i am having trouble with.

Comment: I see. the `index` action you posted above is incorrect by the way. which controller is that?

Comment: to helper you with the `case expression`, we would need to see more code. post your controller's `params` method so we can see your attributes. how are you defining `unlreased books`? or `purchased books`? in the first `when` statement, you can simply give them the route to `new purchases`

Comment: I don't know if that is the correct approach for the models, each user's order will only have one book. Think of an e-commerce site, where a user is allowed to buy one book at a time if they want an early preview.

Comment: "each user order will have only one book"? are you thinking of changing it to `user has_one :book`? what if user wants to buy one book1 and one book2? Models are usually hard to and tricky. but you can't do your controller code or view code until you settle on relationships. otherwise, everytime you change your relations, you'd have to change controller and views, and maybe routes

Comment: oh i redid my models above. sorry i forgot to mention that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52636/discussion-between-wali-ali-and-surge-pedroza)